# PUT request using cURL and flask on windows

Tags: python, curl, put

This is my code snippet for PUT method in my rest web api made using flask.

```
    @app.route('/lock-api/api/v1.0/items/<int:item_id>', methods=['PUT'])
    def update_item(item_id):
    item = [item for item in items if item['id'] == item_id]

    if len(item) == 0:
       abort(404)

    if not request.json:
       abort(400)

    if 'lock state' in request.json and type(request.json['lock state']) != unicode:
       abort(400)

    item[0]['lock state'] = request.json.get('item', item[0]['lock state'])
    return jsonify({'item': item[0]})
```

The curl command for PUT request is

```
    curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "{"""lock state""":""""UNLOCKED"""}" http://localhost:5000/lock-api/api/v1.0/items/2
```

This command is supposed to update the lock state of the entry in the array(items) in the same file with 2 fields 'id' and 'lock state' but is not doing so. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? I tried adding an append but all it does is add an array inside that array instead of updating it.
ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

You have one too many open quotes before "UNLOCKED".

But your command would be simpler if you used single quotes:

```
curl ... -d '{"lock state":"UNLOCKED"}' ...
```